# deleting multiple elements in an array

Tags: c++

i am trying to write a code that will delete all the elements if an array has same element at different index . it works fine for one element deletion or elements at odd index i.e 1,3,5 etc but it neglects one element if the consecutive index have same element.

i have just tried this to get my hands on arrays

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                                     //for deletion
    {
        if(arr[i]==_delete)
        {   
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
           --n;

        }

    }
```

Comment: iterate from the back, then it should work

Comment: Start by using `std::vector` instead of arrays? Will make your life much simpler.

Comment: There is a standard algorithm for this: `std::remove_if`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `std::vector` as a container for your objects.

```
std::vector<TYPE> vec ;
// initialise vector
```

You can use

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                          [](const auto & item){return item == _delete;}), vec.end());
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::list`. Its [list::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) has linear time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional solution, if you want to deal with built-in C++ arrays, the standard `std::remove` algorithm can be rewritten like this:

```
void remove(int _delete) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != _delete) {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    // update the size!
    n = j;
}
```

It's quite pretty:

We keep in the array the elements we only need, and override the ones in which we are not interested (they can be either equal or not to `_delete` and start at position `j` till the end)